# How to make compact.exe to compress only folders, but not files?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, compression

I have a large and complex nested folder structure on disk. Say,

```
Folder1
<many files>
  Subfolder1
  <many files>
  Subfolder2
  <many files>
  ...
  SubfolderNNN
```

Compressing all the files would take few hours, so I would like to set Compressed attribute only on folders. That would leave existing files unchanged, but new files added in the future would become compressed.

Is there a way to achieve that using `compact.exe` command line?

Comment: *A few hours*, then I suggest you do it at nighttime. (Perhaps this is moere suited for Stackoverflow, voting for moving).

Answer (score 1):

It may not be completely clear from the output of `compact /?`, but when you use `compact /c C:\somefolder`, only the folder's compressed attribute is set, while the files inside the folder keep their current compressed attribute unchanged.

What you want to do is:
`compact /c Folder1
cd Folder1
for /f "delims=" %i in ('@dir /b /s /a:d') do compact /c "%i"`.

If you should later intend to compress all the files, repeat the latter two commands, but omit the `/a:d`.